# Should I re-scale the PCA score before classification?

Tags: classification, pca

This question is about using PCA as a dimension reduction method before feeding the data into a classifier. It's a common procedure to use PCA for a data set which contains a large number of features, and to only use the first several PCA-scores instead of the original features. **My question is**: After the PCA score has been extracted should I need to re-scale them ? (as the scores are in descending order...and can be in different magnitude)

Comment: As the score is the proportion of variance explained by this factor. but it doesn't have two be related to the discrimination property. isn't it ?  (sorry for the not so good English)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rescaling is always a good idea. As pointed out by jb. in some cases it won't make a different, but in some cases it will make a significant difference.

Let me add that for PCA related stuff, sometimes subtle differences in the rescaling can make a relatively large difference. Consider evaluating the following alternatives: unit length normalization, linear re-scaling, mean variance rescaling and rank scaling.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the classifier.

Some need to have inputs that have the same magnitude, some not.

Models that AFAIK need scaled data:

- SVM
- Most neural networks
- Fisher model --- I not really sure, but I think so.

Models that don't need it:

- Decision trees

Comment: It's just how stack exchange sites work, no big deal through! 

Read the FAQ